# Connection to host by Unique id, not IP?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program in c++...some kind of server software. And i want to know is it possible to connect to server/host not by IP, but by a unique ID, something like TeamViewer one.

Later edit: I perfectly understand that it's the tcp/ip protocol. My problem is NAT. So smth. like directly entering the host's ip won't work. That's why i want to know how this works (teamviewer).

@Alina Danila: I know that TeamViewer uses TCP/IP, but can't understand how a connection is made if the other user is behind NAT?

Comment: Anything wrong with [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not exactly possible.

TeamViewer is based on TCP/IP, it enables remote connections over port 5900. That means, to connect two TeamViewer clients, you connect to a partner`s PC on port 5900.

Even if you introduce just a code, it might be a unique key based on the IP.

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer's ID is only an abstraction. On the bottom, it uses TCP/IP (hence, it uses IP+PORT) to connect machines.